# Unable to concat and echo the names

Tags: php, string-concatenation

this might look silly to you but I am stuck here . I have some photos uploading and their names are saved like `$photo_name1`,`$photo_name2`....

```
$photo_name1 = $_FILES['pf5']['name'];
$photo_name2 = $_FILES['pf2']['name'];
```

Now I want to retrieve their names in a loop

```
for($i = 1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
echo $photo_name.$i;        

list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $photo_name.$i);
```

The following echo is displaying only 1,2,3...etc . Please help me so that I can retrieve their names within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ${'photo_name'.$i};
```

should do the trick.

Comment: You really should point someone using variable variables towards arrays whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are to use `implode` not `explode`

Am not sure how your `HTML` is constructed but your names should come like this

```
$_FILES['pf5']['name'][0];
$_FILES['pf5']['name'][1];
$_FILES['pf5']['name'][2];
```

Fore it to be like this that means you are using multiple forms .....

```
$photo_name1 = $_FILES['pf5']['name'];
$photo_name2 = $_FILES['pf2']['name'];
```

Imagine this

```
$names = array (); //have name array 
foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $val) {
    $names [] = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key]; //put names to array
}

echo implode(",", $names); // print the names
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename 1:</label> <input type="file" name="image[]"
        id="file" /> <br /> <label for="file">Filename 2:</label> <input
        type="file" name="image[]" id="file" /> <br /> <label for="file">Filename
        3:</label> <input type="file" name="image[]" id="file" /> <br /> <input
        type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make `$photo_name` an array? Then you can simply do

```
echo $photo_name[$i];
```

Furthermore you should use `pathinfo()` to determine file extensions, because when someone names a file `photo.foo.bar.jpg` things will go haywire:

```
$path_info = pathinfo($filename);
$ext = $path_info['extension'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store the names in an array and not in individual variables:

```
$photo_names[1] = $_FILES['pf5']['name'];
$photo_names[2] = $_FILES['pf2']['name'];
```

You can then access one name using `$photo_names[$i]`.